# Interceptar el evento de pegado en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que deberia interceptar el evento de pegado en C#, usando Visual Studio 2019.
Esto es util para el caso de que el usuario copie texto erroneamente, que le falte algun caracter al principio o al final y asi tener la oportunidad de corregirlo y pegar el texto correcto.

En mi programa (que pueden ver mas abajo) no esta capturando el evento WM_PASTE

Cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida!

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);
    
    // Constants
    private const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;
    private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;
    
    public Form1() 
    {            
        AddClipboardFormatListener(Handle);                              
    }   
    
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {            

        // Listen for operating system messages.
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:

        MessageBox.Show(Clipboard.GetText());                                        
                break;

            case WM_PASTE:                    
                MessageBox.Show("PASTE");
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron útiles, gracias

Comment: Si y no, es asi como lo presentan pero no es exactamente el caso

Comment: Ya entiendo, lo que quieres hacer es una especie de keylogger, que detecte las teclas en todo el sistema operativo, esto es mas dificil, pero ojo, un keylogger puede ser detectado por un antivirus como una aplicacion dañina y eliminar tu aplicacion e incluso si lo ejecutas en otras pc podria ser visto como un intento de violacion de la privacidad de la persona, ya que en teoria sabrias que es lo que escribe esta persona y bien podrias capturar las contraseñas que usa esta persona, mucho cuidado con lo que vas a hacer, puede tener consecuencias negativas

Comment: El problema es que el programa no captura el evento WM_PASTE, si bien he visto infinidad de codigo con esto como ejemplo...

Answer (score 0):

mucho gusto saludarte!

No sé que tan amplio sea su proyecto, pero puedo recomendarte una forma muy sencilla, espero sea de utilidad:

Si estás validando en un formulario winforms la entrada del usuario a tavés de cajas de texto, puedes ocupar el evento KeyUp, luego puedes recuperar el texto y realizar las modificaciones requerida, te dejo un ejemplo en el cual agregue un textbox y agregué el evento KeyUp:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) + Convert.ToInt32(Keys.V))
        {
            string ValorPegado = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format(" Texto Pegado:{0} \n Texto Modificado:¡{1}!",ValorPegado));
        }
    }

output:
```

Texto Pegado:Hola mundo
Texto Modificado:¡Hola mundo!

Comment: Tenia pensado que el usuario puede llegar a copiar y pegar desde el Notepad haciendo click con el boton derecho del mouse pero no se si hay un evento que permita esto.

Comment: La idea seria que el usuario copia y pega un texto, yo lo saco del clipboard con el programa, lo valido y lo pego de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de un código que hice hace algún tiempo, lo que hace es que detecta cuando se pega un texto y si la primera letra de lo que se pega es minúscula la pone mayúscula.

Este código va en el **evento KeyPress** del componente(**TextBox**, etcétera):

```
if(bPaste)
{
   if (Clipboard.ContainsText())
   {
      var texto = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
      var primerCaracter = texto[0];

      if (char.IsLower(primerCaracter))
      {
         texto = texto.Remove(0, 1);
         texto = string.Format("{0}{1}", char.ToUpper(primerCaracter), texto);
      }

      Clipboard.SetText(texto);
   }
}
```

**Explicación:**

**bPaste** es una **variable global booleana** que es la que va a detectar si estamos apretando la combinación de **teclas Ctrl + V**, para ello vamos al **evento KeyDown** del componente y ponemos esto:

```
if (e.Control && e.KeyValue == 86)
{
   bPaste = true;
}
```

Aquí se detecta si estamos apretando la **tecla Control** y además la **tecla "v"** o **"V"**(**86** es la **"V"** y da lo mismo que esté activado o no el **CapsLock**). Si esa combinación fue pulsada entonces **bPaste** será **true**.

Ahora vamos al **evento KeyPress**.

Aquí lo que se hace es que vemos si la **variable bPaste** es **true**, de serlo pues vemos si el **Clipboard**(**Portapapeles**) contiene un texto ya que bien podría ser una imagen, un fichero, etcétera. De ser texto pues guardamos en la **variable texto** el contenido del **ClipBoard**(**Portapapeles**) a través de la sentencia:

```
var texto = Clipboard.GetText().Trim();
```

Donde la **función Trim** elimina los espacios en blanco, si dice **"  Hola"** ahora dirá **"Hola"**. Posteriormente guardamos el primer caracter y vemos si es minúscula, de ser minúscula, pues lo convertimos a mayúscula y posteriormente ponemos en el **Portapapeles** el texto ya cambiado mediante la sentencia:

```
Clipboard.SetText(texto);
```

Para hacer uso de la **clase Clipboard** debes asegurarte que en los **usings** tengas:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Te dejo este código para que lo analices y lo adaptes al tuyo.

Comment: El ejemplo que te pongo es para que veas como funciona la clase Clipboard, esta seria la clase que tendrías que utilizar para resolver tu problema, usando los métodos que te describo en el ejemplo

Comment: Refinando, lo que necesito es saber como intercepto el mensaje en el preciso momento en que un usuario pega un texto para poder pegar otro.

Comment: Bue...di enter. No es solo para casillas en un formulario, podria ser entre dos paginas web distintas.